# colorscheme set in .vimrc is not being applied

Tags: vim, color-scheme, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have installed zenburn colorscheme to ~/.vim/colors and am trying to enable it by default in the .vimrc file.

I have added `colorscheme zenburn` to my .vimrc file but the colorscheme is not enabled after vim starts.
If I manually do `:colorscheme zenburn` it sets the colorscheme.

If I enable a colorscheme that comes with vi ( for eg desert ) in vimrc, its being enabled at vim startup.

This is my vimrc

```
filetype plugin on      
filetype indent on      

set nocompatible        
set history=500         
syntax on               
set expandtab           
set tabstop=4           
set shiftwidth=4        
set softtabstop=4       
set number              
set autoindent          
set cindent             
set showmatch           
set matchtime=5         
set ruler               
set laststatus=2        
set hlsearch            
set incsearch           
set cursorline          
set scrolloff=5         
"set nowrap             
set foldenable          
set foldmarker={,}      
set foldmethod=marker   
set foldlevel=100       
"set mouse=a            
"set mouse=r            
colorscheme zenburn
```

What should I do to get zenburn colorscheme enabled at startup ?

Comment: what is your current colorscheme, when you run vim with this setup? (just type `:coloscheme` in vim)

Comment: @qiubix E471: Argument required error is shown if I just give `:colorscheme`

Comment: @k0n3ru this is very strange, as this error message is completely unrelated to the suggested command. Anyway, check the output of `:echo g:colors_name`

Answer (score 5):

In my case when colorscheme was the only command in `.vimrc` it did not work. I had to add `syntax on` command at the end to make it work.

```
$ cat ~/.vimrc
colorscheme zenburn
syntax on
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to load .vimrc file again after vim is started with :source ~/.vimrc
Did the colorscheme changes?

Also if you use graphical vim, there is second file that can override your settings ~/.gvimrc

Comment: Yes the colorscheme changes if I source the vimrc after vim has started.But If I write colorscheme desert , its applied correctly automatically which is not the case with colorscheme zenburn. ( all other settings in the vimrc are applied successfully ) . No I am not overriding any colorschemes in gvimrc. I am using xterm if from cygwin-x if that matters.

Comment: Maybe you have something else that broke your .vimrc. You have several options and checks. In vim you can check how the scripts are loaded with :scriptnames command. you can check my output here: http://pastie.org/10409724. Also in shell try "alias", maybe you have more arguments attached to the vim command.

Comment: another options is your colors to be broken somehow, you can start over using following commands: mv ~/.vim ~/.vim.old;  git clone https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes.git ~/.vim

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, try putting the command for colorscheme at the bottom of .vimrc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found the following solution: in your .cshrc file (or equivalent in your .bashrc file), add the following line:
alias vi 'vim "+colorscheme my_scheme"'
Pay attention to the quotes and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue is caused by running `sudo vim`. I have the colorscheme applied without problems before, but now it refuse to take effect at all. It turns out that by adding `sudo` before `vim`, the program loads `/root/.vimrc` instead of `~/.vimrc`. Just copy the file from your home directory to `/root/` and voila!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the customised colour scheme as the default const `g:colors_name = "zenburn"`.
Make sure there aren't any lines in your `.vimrc` that might be overriding the `colorscheme` zenburn line. For example, another `colorscheme` setting later in the file could be taking precedence. Double-check that you've installed the Zenburn colorscheme in the correct location. It should be in `~/.vim/colors/zenburn.vim`. You can try typing `:verbose colorscheme` into Vim; Vim will display the current color theme and the file location, to help you further troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score -2):

try

```sh
set colorscheme zenburn
# or 
set color zenburn
```